# how to make a class that makes multiple objects?

Tags: ruby, class, object

How can I make a class that makes multiple classes. I have this:

```
class Person

attr_accessor :name
@name = name

def initialize
    Person.new
    Person.new
    Person.new
    Person.new
    Person.new
    Person.new
    Person.new
    Person.new
end
end
```

but that returns stack level to deep.

Comment: you mean multiple classes or objects?

Comment: Objects I guess. I want to make ten people with names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that you are facing is that you are creating a person which in turn is creating 10 other person objects which are all returning 10 person objects. This continues on indefinitely.
What you want is:

```
class Person   
   attr_accessor :name
   @name = name
end

class People
   @people
   def initialize()
      people = []
      for i in 0..10
         people[i] = Person.new
      end
   end
end
```

This creates another object that in turn contains 10 Person objects. This way there is no way for the same recursive problem to happen.

Comment: that returns: NameError: undefined local variable or method `people' for #<People:0x00000001868c50>
 from /home/cairo/Desktop/tutoring/lesson_1.rb:10:in `block in initialize'
 from /home/cairo/Desktop/tutoring/lesson_1.rb:9:in `each'
 from /home/cairo/Desktop/tutoring/lesson_1.rb:9:in `initialize'
 from (irb):2:in `new'
 from (irb):2
 from /home/cairo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'

Comment: It should work now... sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't clear where you wanted to get the names from -- External file? Manual Input? Database?

In any case, you could probably do something like:

```
class Person
    attr_accessor :name

    def initialize(name)
        self.name = name
    end
end
##some sort of input goes here and creates the array of names
arrayofnames = [name1,name2,name3]
arrayofnames.each do |person|
    Person.new(person)
end
```

As part of the same enumeration you could put each new person into an array or store them somewhere else for later use. Here I built the class and added the people to it separately, although you could probably build the same enumeration into the class itself.

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is your `Person` class:

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
end
```

If you want another class to create `x` number of `Person` instances you can use the following `PeopleCreator` class:

```
class PeopleCreator
  def self.create_person_for(names)
    new.create(names)
  end

  def create(names)
    names.map { |name| Person.new(name) }
  end
end
```

I've used a `class` method in the `PeopleCreator` to be able to easily call the following:

```
names = %w(John Jane Jake)
PeopleCreator.create_person_for(names)
# => [#<Person:0x0000000a743150 @name="John">, #<Person:0x0000000a743128 @name="Jane">, #<Person:0x0000000a743100 @name="Jake">]
```